# Python Equality Comparison

Tags: python

I came across a equality comparison problem in python 2.7. I ran the following program,expecting that `elist[i][1] == MC` will return `True`.

```
elist=elist=[[1,1],[2,4],[3,9]]
MC=0
while (MC<1.01):
    MC+=0.01
    for i in range(len(elist)):
        #test equality
        print elist[i][1]
        print MC
        print elist[i][1]==int(MC)
```

But it came out as:

```
1
1.0
False
4
1.0
False
9
1.0
False
```

Even I change into:

```
float(elist[i][1])==float(MC)
```

It still returns the same result.

Does anybody know why this happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to compare floats for almost-equality in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python)

Comment: What did you expect?

Comment: Ref: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the way that most computers handle floating point numbers. 0.1 is an irrational binary number, like 1/3 is in decimal. A simpler demonstration is `print(0.1+0.1+0.1)` which prints `0.30000000000000004`. That number would be seen as different to to 0.3 if I compare with `==`. You should compare for almost-equality in this case, as noted in the comment above.